# Android circular imageview with two borders CROPPED

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin.android

I'm attempting to make a circular imageView with two borders.

The circular image is made with a [library](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CircleImageView-Xamarin.Android) that only allows to make one border, with the `app:civ_border_color` property.

The **second** border is achieved by setting a background property.

My problem is, the second border, made with the background, is being cropped on the sides, like this:

[image]

---

**The circular image**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/mrwhite"
    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#BF0404" />
```

**The second border**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

  <stroke
      android:width="5dp"
      android:color="#F2F2F2" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `thicknessRatio` value to **2**

```
android:thicknessRatio="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to create `RoundedImageView` using `ImageView` and `CardView`

Check this example: https://github.com/SergeySharipov/RoundedImageView

Add the following dependency to your app module's **build.gradle** file:

```
 dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
 }
```

Add the code to your layout and change "YOUR_PICTURE":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_for_image"
        android:foreground="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rounded_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/YOUR_PICTURE" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Create **shape.xml** in drawable and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#f44336" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```